# Django: Aggregate through a model_set's model_set

Tags: python, django, django-models

These are my models:

```
class Streamer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

class Account(models.Model):
    streamer = models.ForeignKey(Streamer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Account Name", max_length=100, null=True)


class Stream(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField("Score", default=0)
```

A Streamer can have multiple accounts queried through an account_set.

An Account can have multiple streams associated to it through a stream_set.

So how can I get all of the streams associated to all of the accounts associated to the Streamer?

Hope that makes sense lol.

It basically needs to be something like (not an accurate example):

```
streamer = Streamer.objects.all()[0] # Get first streamer

streamer.account_set.stream_set.count()
```

for example, or something like this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query with the `Stream` model:

```
Stream.objects.filter(host__streamer=streamer).count()
```

You can make use of `.annotate(..)` to sum the `score`s togethers and then order for example by the `total_score`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Streamer.objects.annotate(
    total_score=Sum('account__stream__score')
).order_by('total_score')
```

Comment: Wow, I was thinking in the total opposite direction haha. But this totally works.

I think the reason I was looking in the other direction is because I'm trying to figure out how to make a "total score" on that I can sort by on the Streamer model.

For example, I want to do `streamers= Streamer.objects.all().order_by("total_score")'.

Or 'Streamer.objects.all().order_by('host__stream__score').

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @ZackPlauché: the total score is then the sum of the `score` of the `Stream`s with a `host` that points to an `Account that points to the streamer?

Comment: Yes, the wording was a bit hard to put together haha. 

I need to make a list of streamers that are sorted by the highest score, which is calculated by adding up all of the stream scores. Basically account is the bridge here.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Definitely overlooked the annotate method!

Comment: @ZackPlauché: you can sort in descending order (so highest total score first) with `.order_by('-total_score')`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answers were extremely helpful.

Comment: I have another question you may be able to answer on a similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952001/django-annotate-a-filtered-reverse-relationship

Answer (score 2):

Reading your comment to Willem Van Onsem, if you want to get the total score per streamer you'll want to use Django's aggregate functionality.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/

is a good starting point.

specifically this section seems pertinent: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards

for your specific case I think something along these lines should work?

```
Streamer.objects.annotate(total_score=Sum("account__streamer__score"))
```

I'm a little rusty on my orm foo so that might need to be tweaked but I think it should work!

Notice that I omit `set` from the joins I make. It's a bit of a quirk but you don't include the set when making joins, only when referencing the M2M manager on a model instance.

Edit: Didn't see that Willem Van Onsem had updated his answer to use aggregates whoops! That being said the docs are a good reference so I'll keep my post.

Comment: I have another question you might be able to answer on a similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952001/django-annotate-a-filtered-reverse-relationship

Comment: Didn't see this soon enough! Glad it was answered though